# Some sub-category URLs goes to a 404 page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have seven categories under Default Category, and a number of sub-categories under the main seven.

I am getting a 404 error; when I go to a couple of the sub-categories under two of the main categories! All other category URLs under the categories and sub-categories work fine.

Example:

> 1. cat-1
>
>    - cat-1/sub-1-1 (noerror)
>    - **cat-1/sub-1-2 (404)**
>    - cat-1/sub-1-3 (noerror)
>    - cat-1/sub-1-4 (noerror)
> 2. cat-2
>
>    - **cat-2/sub-2-1 (404)**
>    - **cat-2/sub-2-2 (404)**
>    - cat-2/sub-2-3 (noerror)
>    - cat-2/sub-2-4 (noerror)
>    - cat-2/sub-2-5 (noerror)
>    - cat-2/sub-2-6 (noerror)

When hovering over the category URLs the links look as follow:

> domainDOTcom/cat-1
>   domainDOTcom/cat-1/sub-1-1
>   **domainDOTcom/cat-1/sub-1-2**
>   domainDOTcom/cat-1/sub-1-3
>   domainDOTcom/cat-1/sub-1-4
>
> domainDOTcom/cat-2
>   **domainDOTcom/cat-2/sub-2-1**
>   **domainDOTcom/cat-2/sub-2-2**
>   domainDOTcom/cat-2/sub-2-3
>   domainDOTcom/cat-2/sub-2-4
>   domainDOTcom/cat-2/sub-2-5
>   domainDOTcom/cat-2/sub-2-6

The 404 error link looks like:

> domainDOTcom/cat-1/index.php?main_page=page_not_found
>   domainDOTcom/cat-2/index.php?main_page=page_not_found

**Note**: And also from admin I have Flushed Cache Storage, Flushed Magento Cache, Re-freshed all cache types.

And via SSH I have re-indexed all as follow:
`magento/shell
php indexer.php --reindexall`
This didn't do it either.

What could be causing this?

Comment: try to rebuild your indexes

Comment: @Marius I have done that, with no results.  I am doing it again. Will keep you posted. The only thing I haven't done, is to physically delete all cache and session files from var/! Thanks.

Comment: I finished re-indexing all, and I am still getting the 404 errors.  `Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully in 00:01:02`
`Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:59`
`Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:23:28`
`Category Products index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:10`
`Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:01:07`
`Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00`
`Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00`

Comment: @Marius I did another test. Under Admin>Catalog>Manage Categories, I moved sub-category **sub-1-2** from category **cat-1** to **Default Category** (one level up), then by clicking on sub-1-2 (no longer a sub) all products are displayed, without any errors! But when I move back **sub-1-2** to **cat-1** it displays the error again.